# Focus stealing under Xfce in Matlab (Java programs?)

Tags: xfce, java, matlab, focus

I'm using Matlab R2015a under Debian Linux. I recently switched to Xfce 4.12 as my desktop environment, and since then I am experiencing weird focus behavior:

When I try to interact with the documentation window or a figure window using the mouse, the focus switches to the main Matlab window. The problem does not occur using the keyboard.

Since the Matlab GUI is written in Java, I suspect but am not sure that this is not actually a Matlab problem but might occur in other Java GUIs as well.

Does someone know what causes this and how to get rid of it?

Comment: @Braiam, why did you remove the "focus" tag? Other questions tagged with it use it in the same meaning as I do.

Comment: @Braiam, but it isn't the only tag... I don't understand, focus stealing is the main point of the question, the other tags indicate the context.

Comment: @Braiam, as I said, because that's the main point. Why would you remove it? ;-) But whatever, as long as someone can give an answer...

Comment: Is already in your title, so having it on tags wouldn't bring any benefits to you. Having xfce and java tags is more relevant than something vague about "focus".

Comment: Is your problem the same as this [problem](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/338444)?

Comment: @StrongBad, thanks, but I don't think so. I'm not using KDE (anymore) and not twm, and my problem is not just that events go to the underlying window but that the focus is switched completely. I do use different keyboard layouts though, and I'll check whether fiddling with them solves the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems to be somehow related to the keyboard layout switcher. Try switching your keyboard layout to it's initial setting. See #16 [here](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/10430)